# What do I type in as the value for the filmList parameter?

Tags: haskell, custom-data-type

```
data Film = Film String String Int [String] deriving (Eq, Ord, Show, Read)
--that's my custom data type, (Film *filmname, director, year of release, fans)

addFilm :: Film -> [Film] -> [Film]
addFilm newFilm filmList = filmList ++ [newFilm]

--this is for adding a new film to the list, but without the fans string array
```

The module is loading into WinGHCi with no errors, but I don't know what to put in place of filmList.

```
---
<interactive>:63:30:
    Couldn't match type `Char' with `Film'
    Expected type: [Film]
      Actual type: [Char]
    In the second argument of `addFilm', namely `"Jordan Vogt-Roberts"'
    In the expression:
      addFilm "Kong: Skull Island" "Jordan Vogt-Roberts" 2017
    In an equation for `it':
        it = addFilm "Kong: Skull Island" "Jordan Vogt-Roberts" 2017
*Main> addFilm "Kong: Skull Island" "Jordan Vogt-Roberts" 2017 filmList

<interactive>:64:57: Not in scope: `filmList' --- that's what I input.
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to use the data constructor, not just the arguments to it. If you want to create a value of type `Film`, you need to write for example: `Film "Kong: Skull Island" "Jordan Vogt-Roberts" 2017 ["Fan One","Fan Two"]`.

More specifically a data declaration like `data TypeName = DataConstructor String` creates a function `DataConstructor :: String -> TypeName`. In your case, that is `Film :: String -> String -> Int -> [String] -> Film`.

Example:

```
skullIsland = Film "Kong: Skull Island" "Jordan Vogt-Roberts" 2017 ["Fan One","Fan Two"]
otherMovie = Film "Movie Name" "The Director" 2000 ["Lazersmoke","Saad"]

addFilm skullIsland [otherMovie,otherMovie]
```

> but without the fans string array

I'm not sure I understand what you are trying to do; the fans list is part of your data type, you can't just ignore it.

Comment: I think I meant with empty string of fans, not "without it". Sorry and thanks.